# Negative value for date.getTIme()

Tags: android, date, datetime

While getting time for a particular date i get negative value. what could be the reason for it.My code like this. i have two string value which stores the creation and due date  and creating two dates date1 and date2 for respectively.When i check for the the long value i get negative values .My Logcat is also there.

```
Log.i("Cdate ",cdate);
        Log.i("Ddate ",ddate);
    datesdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            try
            {
                date1=datesdf.parse(cdate);
                date2=datesdf.parse(ddate);
            }
            catch (ParseException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    long creationdate=date1.getTime();
            long duedatee=date2.getTime();
            Log.i("Creation date",Long.toString(creationdate));
            Log.i("Due date",Long.toString(duedatee));
```

Logcat::

```
02-08 11:29:10.020: I/Cdate(1244): 8-1-2013
02-08 11:29:10.020: I/Ddate(1244): 08-0-2013
02-08 11:29:10.030: I/Creation date(1244): -61741117800000
02-08 11:29:10.030: I/Due date(1244): -61743796200000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data format used for parsing does not match the way you specified the date. The dates you get are in the year 8.

Comment: yes i found that.. as i wrote the question i found that silly mistake..! thanks anyways..!

Answer (score 1):

Your date format is wrong. You need to change to

```
 datesdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

assuming 8-1-2013 represents 8th Jan 2013.